# ¿Cómo muevo todos los archivos de un directorio a otro directorio dependiendo de su nombre?

Tags: linux, bash, script

Tengo un directorio con mas de 10.000 archivos .rar el cual tienen nombre distintos ejemplo:

```
ARCHIVO_123_740.rar
ARCHIVO_123_741.rar
ARCHIVO_123_742.rar
ARCHIVO_124_740.rar
ARCHIVO_124_741.rar
ARCHIVO_124_742.rar
```

Como pueden observar tengo archivos distintos con nombres parecidos.

Quisiera saber cómo podría generar un script o qué me recomiendan para crear directorios donde se MUEVAN los archivos 123 al directorio 123 y los 124 al directorio 124 y si no existe el directorio lo crea.

Comment: Cabe resaltar que quiero hacer un Script en Bash o algo similar para ejecutarlo desde mi servidor Debian

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado, Saul?

Comment: Lo hice manualmente, nadie me respondió a tiempo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre esto, aunque lo he probado con la lista que pones, funcina

```
#!/bin/bash

ls ./*.rar > file 
awk '{print (substr ($1,11,3)) }' file | uniq > creadir

for f in `cat creadir`
do
    mkdir -p $f
done

for i in `cat creadir` 
do    
    find . -name "*$i*" -exec mv {} ./$i \;  > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podría resultarte el comando: " mv [Opciones] fuente destino "

usandolo de esta manera

```
$ mv [Opciones] ARCHIVO_123* destino
```

Comment: Y lo mismo para "ARCHIVO_124"

Answer (score 0):

alguien puede solucionarme unas preguntas? Estoy usando este programa para mi uso y lo estoy reusando pero no entiendo partes del programa. Haya voy:
-Después de file, ponemos uniq > creadir, entiendo que significa que si es único se vaya a la función creadir?
-luego mete dos bucles `cat creadir`, no entiendo la función cat. En el primer bucle entiendo que se dice que cree un directorio pero no entiendo de -p $f, ¿que son esos dos valores?
-En el ultimo bucle, entiendo que busca el archivo, y lo mueva a esa carpeta pero tampoco entiendo el $i, y sino devuelva error.
Si alguien pudiera ayudarme, estaría muy agradecido. 
Un saludo

Comment: Te recomiendo que abras una pregunta nueva, realmente la has planteado donde debería de ir una respuesta. En su defecto también puedes hacer un comentario como el mío dentro de éste hilo. Mantengamos el orden ;-)

Comment: No me deja hacer un comentario, y abrir una pregunta relaccionado con este tema, me parece que seria abrir muchas preguntas no?